fill legend symbol in geom_sf object not reducing size
I would like to reduce the size of the symbols of the legend bug the following code is not working. It does work if i want to increase the size of the symbols though.Is there a way we can make it smaller beyond the original?
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

ggplot(nc[1:2,])+geom_sf(aes(fill=NAME))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
        plot.margin = margin(0., 0., 0., 0., "cm"), plot.background = element_rect(
          fill='white',
          colour = "black",
          size = 1),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black",fill='lightgrey'),
        legend.box.margin = margin(t = 1, l = 1))+
          guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))
#try changing the size lower than 5 and it doesn't do anything in the guides section  


ggplot(nc[1:2,]) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME)) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
    plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = "black", size = 1),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = 'lightgrey'),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm")  # Adjust the size of the legend key here
  )


